# Setting up onTouch Listeners on specific x,y points on screen

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am trying to set up onTouch Listeners for exact x,y points on the device screen. If the user hovers over these points it would trigger something else in the app.

I'm wondering is there a way to set up an onTouchListener for an x,y position on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    if(x == desiredPointX && y == desiredPointY)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
    }

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The motion event contains all the information you need.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int)event.getX();
   int y = (int)event.getY();
   if(x && y in some place){
     _do your work
     return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
```