# Regions in Android, basic touch implementing

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, region

I found out in one of my [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890800/setting-up-ontouch-listeners-on-specific-x-y-points-on-screen) that setting up specific x,y coordinates as Touch Listeners was too specific and that just one position would be too small to pick up a touch input.

@ligi mentioned `Regions` in a comment under my question. I looked into it and realised that it's what I need, I just can't find out how to implement one.

Here is the code for a TouchListener for a specific x,y coordinate:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (!mDragging) {
        return false;
    }

    int x = (int) ev.getX();
    int y = (int) ev.getY();

    if (x == 100 && y == 200) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.e(TAG, "ACTION DOWN");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.e(TAG, "ACTION MOVE");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.e(TAG, "ACTION UP");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to set up a Region instead? Say if a user finger moves into the region area, do something. I can't find any basic implementations anywhere else.

Here's an image if the desc. wasn't clear:

[image]

Comment: @AmitApollo and zgc7009 Thanks a million for the answers. I'm gonna try them both out and see how they work. I will publish my progress later. Thanks again!

Comment: @zgc7009 see above comment

Comment: You're welcome Gurfuffle. You can also use Region too. Region has an intrinsic function called getBounds() which the return type is Rect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    int x = (int) ev.getX();
    int y = (int) ev.getY();

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.e(TAG, "ACTION DOWN OR MOVE");

            // check if the event is in region 1
            if(x >= "left_x_region1" && x <= "right_x_region1"
                && y >= "top_x_region1" && y <= "bottom_x_region1")
                // do something for region1

            // check if the event is in region 2
            else if(x >= "left_x_region2" && x <= "right_x_region2"
                && y >= "top_x_region2" && y <= "bottom_x_region2")
                // do something for region1

            // continue for other cases
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.e(TAG, "ACTION UP");
            break;
    }
}
```

Or you could simplify it even further by making a list of what those actual values are, or even better create Rects from those values

```
List<Rect> regions = new ArrayList<Rect>();
regions.add(new Rect("left_x_region1", "top_y_region1", "right_x_region1", "bottom_y_region1");
regions.add(new Rect("left_x_region2", "top_y_region2", "right_x_region2", "bottom_y_region2");
// continue for each region
```

and then check your event in those regions inside your ACTION_DOWN || ACTION_MOVE section of the switch statement

```
for(int i = 0; i < regions.size(); i++){
    if(regions.get(i).contains(x, y)){
       // do stuff for region i
       return;
    }
}
```

What this does is checks to see if the motion event occurred within the bounds of the region.

Comment: Thanks @zgc7009. I got this working in my project, looks like it's what I need!

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you'd use a rect in Android. You'd specify the rectangle(s) and see if the rect(s) contains your value. In the example below I made a list of rectangles so there are multiple hotspots. You could ideally just use one if you want just one specific rectangular region. The .contains internal method allows you to specify regions which your x,y coordinates would potentially entail.

```
 List<Rect> retangles;
```

...

```
 for(Rect rect : rectangles){
    if(rect.contains(x,y)){
        System.out.println("Touched Rectangle, do what you need to do.");
     }
 }
```

or for just one

```
  Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100);

  if(rect.contains(x,y))
    System.out.println("Touched Rectangle, do what you need to do.");
```